# View in a relational database

Tags: database, view

What is the purpose of a view and are views stored on disk?

I know what views are doing in a relational database but cannot find its purpose and whether
they are stored on disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.

A view is simply that -- a view of the data not directly represented by the table themselves.

Typically such views are logically created, and no extra data is stored.

However, some DBs (notably Oracle, perhaps others) have the concept of a "Materialized View" which IS store and maintained by the database, giving better read performance (potentially) than a logical view, at the cost of storage and the syncing operations on normal data.